# how to publish excel dashboard in web page

Tags: html, vba

Whenever I publish my sheet in web page , I have to use slider to see whole sheet. Id there any way to publish my excel in a webpage with the same zoom that is applied in excel so that it can be seen completely in one screen

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But not straightforward.

**Option 1: Edit the CSS of the HTM file**

1. Export file as HTM
2. Open the source code of `stylesheet.css` file and add anywhere:  `body{ zoom:0.75;}`. 
   You can change the zoom by modifying the parameter `zoom`. Add any additional CSS if needed (e.g. change column width). Below 75% zoom.

**Option 2: Modify the font-size etc. in the original file**

1. Modify the font-size etc. in the original file (instead of zoom-in/out)
2. Export file as HTM

### Instructions for Option1

**Save as HTM:**
[image]
**Insert `body{ zoom:0.75;}` into `stylesheet.css`**
[image]
**The effect:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: I tried to save Dashboard in HTMl Format, got the source code, copy it in notepad and got a list of tables; i do modify font_size and font-weight but not luck.I do try to add CSS, but that also no luck. Can you please let me know what can I do now?